# Stacking <ul> elements and the <li> within them - mobile design

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to make a mobile version of an OrgChart I created; however, I am having trouble with trying to stack my `ul` and `li` elements in the way that I want them. Essentially, I need the elements to stack on one another like my crudely drawn ms paint here:

[image]

What I have now is a series of `ul` elements nested within some `li` elements. Each `ul` element nested within the `li` element suggests that said element is the parent to one or more `li` elements. See CodePen: http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/xwLmWo

I couldn't care less about the connectors right now but I am having a hard time understanding how I'd stack these elements. I'm relatively new when it comes to HTML/CSS... Hell, if this is achievable with some JavaScript I'm all ears for that as well; however, this will be for mobile (i.e. when the screen width is very tiny).

Here's a sample of how my HTML is set up:

```
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="ss_menu">
        <a class="ss_button"><span>Director </span></a>
        <div class="ss_content">
          <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121227201208/jamesbond/images/6/61/Generic_Placeholder_-_Profile.jpg" width="70px" style="border: 1px solid #000;"/><br/>
        </div>
      </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div id="ss_menu">
          <a class="ss_button"><span>Assistant to the Director </span></a>
          <div class="ss_content">
            <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121227201208/jamesbond/images/6/61/Generic_Placeholder_-_Profile.jpg" width="70px" style="border: 1px solid #000;"/><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div id="ss_menu">
              <a class="ss_button"><span>Deputy Director </span></a>
              <div class="ss_content">
                <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121227201208/jamesbond/images/6/61/Generic_Placeholder_-_Profile.jpg" width="70px" style="border: 1px solid #000;"/><br/>
              </div>
            </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="just-line"><br/><br/><br/></a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div id="ss_menu">
                    <a class="ss_button"><span>Associate Director </span></a>
                    <div class="ss_content">
                      <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121227201208/jamesbond/images/6/61/Generic_Placeholder_-_Profile.jpg" width="70px" style="border: 1px solid #000;"/><br/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" class="just-line"><br/><br/><br/></a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#" class="just-line"><br/><br/><br/></a>
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#"><span>Consumer Laws &amp; Regulations</span></a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div id="ss_menu">
                <a class="ss_button"><span>Senior Associate Director </span></a>
                <div class="ss_content">
                  <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121227201208/jamesbond/images/6/61/Generic_Placeholder_-_Profile.jpg" width="70px" style="border: 1px solid #000;"/><br/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="just-line"><br/><br/><br/></a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#" class="just-line"><br/><br/><br/></a>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <div id="ss_menu">
                            <a class="ss_button"><span>Assistant Director </span></a>
                            <div class="ss_content">
                              <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121227201208/jamesbond/images/6/61/Generic_Placeholder_-_Profile.jpg" width="70px" style="border: 1px solid #000;"/><br/>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#"><span>Examiner Training </span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#"><span>Supervision Administration </span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                              <a href="#"><span>Reserve Bank Oversight</span></a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I don't by any means expect anyone to do it for me. I'm just having trouble with the concept of trying to stack `ul` elements within a `li` element. I've tried a few things; mainly observing how it is handled in this helpful CodePen: http://codepen.io/siiron/pen/aLkdE; however, I'm having trouble translating as the code isn't commented or explained. I'd like to understand what is happen. I've search for the past ~hour trying various things but I fear that my wording doesn't satisfy Google. I figured I'd try here. I mean, I am only looking for a tip/trick/hint/etc.

Comment: You mean like this - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/wKrxLK

Comment: Well, yeah. I've done a mock-up myself: http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/gaGjEV?editors=110. The problem isn't so much that I don't know the concept of how to do it. But instead, translating it? Again, not sure how to word it. I can't make sense of the HTML differences I think is the real problem.

Comment: It's the conversion of what I have into what I need... I don't know how else to put it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use an ID for multiple objects, normally the practice is to use them one time and for jQuery / Javascript functionality. I'd change ss_menu to a class. As for as the style on mobile I'd use a media query and start with this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .tree li a, li{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;    
  }
}
```